# Как программно поменять картинку в UIImageView?

Tags: xcode

У меня в приложении присутствуют 2 картинки `1_big.png` и `2_big.png`.
Я в компиляторе выставляю сразу что сначала грузиться `1_big.png`.
Задача, нажать на кнопку и чтоб картинка поменялась в моём `UIImageView` на `2_big.png`.
Но ничего не происходит. Подскажите, как правильно.

код кнопки:

```
-(IBAction)PressButton:(id)sender;

{

BigImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2_big.png"]];

}
```

Comment: BigImageView.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2_big.png"]];
теперь работает))

Comment: BigImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2_big.png"]; 
Вот так только.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (self.imgView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"1_big.png"])
{        
    [self.imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2_big.png"]];
}
else
{        
    [self.imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1_big.png"]];
}
```